# How can I use a dropdown menu in Google Sheets filter out data and populate cells for a an expense tracker?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-sheets-dates, vlookup

I have created a personal expense tracker (budget) that uses google form responses and categorizes them by fortnights and expenditure categories. This has been successful on a sheet called 'Yearly Expenses - All Categories'. Now, on a separate sheet called 'Weekly Expenditure', I want to use the data from 'Yearly Expenses - All Categories' and create 2 drop down menus - one to sort the fortnightly ranges, one to sort the categories so I can see expenditure of a specific category in a specific time period. It would be nice to allow a 'select all' in these dropdowns as well.

I have (somewhat) figured out how to make the dropdowns (except the 'select all' functionality). Now I am trying to populate the data from the 'Yearly Expenses - All Categories' sheet to the 'Weekly Expenditure' sheet based off the responses to the drop down answers. For example, when the date '24/12/2020' and the category 'groceries' is selected from the 2 drop downs, 'Yearly Expenses - All Categories' sheet to the 'Weekly Expenditure' cells **B2** (total expense amount), **C2** (total amount budgeted for the expense category) and **D2** (the amount above or below the budgeted amount) self populate.

Here is a copy of what I have been doing... Any help would be appreciated!
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1p6vceubE2nJnVNhvCeS5TNm3mJtIFrktDryoM-6pti8/edit?usp=sharing